# SQL Output of NULL values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables in the database: cities, categories and organizations

cities

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | london |
| 2 | new york |
| 3 | berlin |

categories

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | doctor |
| 2 | lawyer |
| 3 | psychologist |

orgs

| id | name | category_id | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john doe | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | max muster | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | erika schmidt | 3 | 3 |

I would like to get an overview with all cities and under each city each category should be displayed with the number of corresponding organizations.

```
**London**
doctor: 12
lawyer: 15
psychologist: 9

**Berlin**
doctor: 22
lawyer: 17
psychologist: 11
```

With the following query I output all cities:

```
SELECT name FROM cities
```

And with the following query I output categories and number of organizations:

```
SELECT 
c.name AS category_name, 
COUNT (o.id) AS org_number
FROM categories c LEFT JOIN orgs o ON c.id = o.cat_id
WHERE o.city_id = $placeId 
GROUP BY c.name 
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

$placeId is is the id of the corresponding city

The data is output as desired.

**The only thing I am missing is that the NULL values are not output.**

Like this:

```
**New York**
doctor: 22
lawyer: **0**
psychologist: **0**
```

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Move the o.city_id condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce the whole combination of city/category with a cross join between those tables. Then, you can join that result with the organization table, as in:

```
select c.name as city, a.name as category, count(o.city_id) as cnt
from cities c
cross join categories a
left join orgs o on o.city_id = c.id and o.category_id = a.id
group by c.id, a.id
order by c.id, a.id
```

Result:

```
 city      category      cnt 
 --------- ------------- --- 
 london    doctor        0   
 london    lawyer        1   
 london    psychologist  0   
 new york  doctor        1   
 new york  lawyer        0   
 new york  psychologist  0   
 berlin    doctor        0   
 berlin    lawyer        0   
 berlin    psychologist  1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cd70165f63d04cc4c9bfe8ff2ec3c1f).